# ssh to multi servers

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

is there a way to make a script to act like a host file,

so i would like to say

```
./test1
```

and it ask me what's the name of the server i type "server1" and the script grap the IP address from a file and ssh to it, i manged to make it work with sshpass but not without the ip !

```
while read -p 'Enter the ip address for the server: ' ip_addr && [[ -z "$ip_addr" ]] ; do
 echo " please, no blank IP address!"

 sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $ip_addr "x=$y"  /bin/bash << "EOF"
                        sudo su - $x
```

Comment: that script fragment is broken.  missing the ending "EOF" to start with.

Comment: thank you, this is a part of the script not all of it

Comment: i guessed that.  the problem is that it's not a [minimum **working** example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example)

Comment: Not an answer, but you should really look at Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- create a Textfile with all the hosts to ssh to
- read the file line by line, and execute something there

Textfile:

```
host1 #comment
host2 # also comment
host3 # # # it does not matter whats after the hostname
```

script:

```
cat Textfile | while read srv comment do;
sshpass -p "$password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@${srv} "COMMANDS"
done
```

For the Password Thing: You should consider replacing the Password with public key authentication. For that to work, you Need to

- create a local ssk keypair with 'ssh-keygen ...'
- add the public key to the remote systems authorized keys with 'ssh-copy-id ..'

Comment: I will try it thank you so much